# How to fetch random image from camera-roll using react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, camera-roll

I have requirement where i need to get a random image every time when i click an button. I don't want picker to come up for the camera-roll with images, instead random image should selected from the camera folder and display in the image view. 
I have followed the official FB tutorial of camera roll. Please find the code as below

```
_handleButtonPress = () => {
   CameraRoll.getPhotos({
       first: 20,
       assetType: 'Photos',
     })
     .then(r => {
       this.setState({ photos: r.edges });
     })
     .catch((err) => {

     });
   };
```

But this code will select the recently clicked images and display in the picker. Instead of to randomly select the uri of the image and display in the imageview. Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Sharath

Comment: @ReyHaynes ooh is it soo?

Comment: @ReyHaynes Yes, i got. But implementation wise it should be still possible. Because i had implemented in native android.

Comment: @ReyHaynes you mean say in react-native its not possible without showing picker right?

Comment: Deleting my responses. Will provide you with a working answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially have the photos and all the necessary metadata once you set the state: `this.setState({ photos: r.edges })`

All you have to do is pick a random image from there. Here's how I did it:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Image,
  CameraRoll,
  Button
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      img: null
    }
  }

  getRandomImage = () => {
    const fetchParams = {
      first: 25,
    }

    CameraRoll.getPhotos(fetchParams)
      .then(data => {
        const assets = data.edges
        const images = assets.map((asset) => asset.node.image)
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)
        this.setState({
          img: images[random]
        })
      })
      .catch(err => console.log)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        { this.state.img ?
          <Image
            style={styles.image}
            source={{ uri: this.state.img.uri }}
          />
          : null
        }
        <Button title="Get Random Image from CameraRoll" onPress={this.getRandomImage}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  image: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '75%',
    margin: 10,
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i will check and let you know.

Comment: i checked and it worked well, thanks @ReyHanes